# string interpolation preserving quotes in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, perl, jq

I have to format body of a json that gets some values substituted from user environment variables. Trying to find a way via shopt or something so the json string is substituted correctly in bash script  but preserves/puts back the double quotes to be a valid json. Tried preprocessing quotes and double quoting.

Example:

```
$ export env_var1=val1
$ export env_var2=val2
$ export args='{"key1": "${env_var1}", "key2": "${env_var2}"}'
$ echo $args #original input
$ eval echo $args #bad output- variables interpolated but quotes lost
Expected output= {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
```

Edit: My constraint here is I do not know the arbitrary json string in advance and I cannot reformat it by hand because the structure or names are not known to me in advance. I do not need to solve *this* specific case - its a toy example. I am trying to formulate a generic solution for an arbitrary string of which the example is a representative. The keys , values or both could be env variables. The json could be arbitrarily nested and large.

Comment: The `%` on your prompt indicates you are using zsh and not bash.  Also you are going to want to ensure not to use curly quotes in any actual code.

Comment: Didn’t get your point about curly braces? Its part of valid json, I put in the code as a sample.

Comment: ok. keyboard error typing on phone. I will edit it.

Comment: If you're looking for a generic solution you're going to need some way to identify for which keys you want to replace values. I'd say that's a totally different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, with those exact variables, you could use `envsubst`:

```
$ export env_var1=val1
$ export env_var2=val2
$ export args='{"key1": "${env_var1}", "key2": "${env_var2}"}'
$ echo "$args" | envsubst
{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
```

But note that it a) will expand any environment variables, not just those matching `env_*`, and b) will not quote any of the contents to make them into valid JSON. E.g. with `env_var1='double"quote'`, you get `{"key1": "double"quote", ...`, with broken quoting.

To fix that first issue, you could do something like this in Bash, to get a string containing a list of the variable names matching `env_*` to `envsubst`:

```
$ echo "$args" | envsubst "$(printf '$%s ' "${!env_@}")"
{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
```

(the problem is that it requires the leading `$` signs.)

For the second, you'd have to preprocess the variables before passing them to `envsubst`, or pass them through `jq`.

Something like this would generate `--arg` options for `jq` for all variables named like `env_*`, and change any `"${foo}"` from the input string to `$foo` so that `jq` recognizes them as variables (note that it would also change any unrelated matching strings):

```
#!/bin/bash

args=(); 
for varname in "${!env_@}"; do
    args+=(--arg "$varname" "${!varname}");
done;
jq -n -c -M "${args[@]}" "$(sed -E -e 's/"\$\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}"/$\1/g' <<< "$1")"
```

Run with:

```bsh
$ export env_var1='double"quote' env_var2=foobar
$ bash jsonexpand.sh '{"key1": "${env_var1}", "key2": "${env_var2}"}'
{"key1":"double\"quote","key2":"foobar"}
```

Comment: envsubst was what I need. Thanks for adding caveats.

Answer (score 3):

You could escape the quotes:

```
{\"key1\": \""$env_var1"\", "key2": \""$env_var2"\"}
```

You could use jq:

```
jq -n --arg one "$env_var1" --arg two "$env_var2" '{key1: $one, key2: $two}'
```

Or [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo):

```
jo key1="$env_var1" key2="$env_var2"
```

I often times use heredocs for complex json objects:

```
read -rd '' json <<EOF
{
    key1: "$env_var1",
    key2: "$env_var2"
}
EOF
echo "$json"
```

Comment: heredocs seems to solve my use case if I know the string in advance. But again if I get the raw string as $ args = ‘the json’ and try to put that in heredocs it stops interpolation.

Comment: @asterisk: You should update your question to more accurately describe your problem including a sample of what your input would be

Comment: The input is arbitrary but valid json with some ${xyz} variables. I need to treat the string as blackbox. The input and expected output are just sample.

Comment: @asterisk: so are the key values ones that will exist already or you need to add new keys regardless of what exists?

Comment: If the variables' values are unknown, then inserting them into JSON with simple variable expansions as in your first and last code example is a no-go. The values need to pass through `jq` or `jo` to be properly encoded.

Comment: Either some of the keys or some of the values or a few of them both could be a env variables. The output should be valid json ( unless the environment is missing some variable values)

Comment: If you use the read / heredoc version, and also have `set -e` in your script, the read will also return non-zero, interrupting your script. The solution is something like `read -rd '' json <<EOF || true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the expression so that the shell doesn't parse it. In the trivial case,

```
echo '{"key1": "var1", "key2": "var2"}'
```

In your case, where you need interpolation of variables, any of these options can work

```
printf '{"key1": "%s", "key2": "%s"}\n' "$env_var1" "$env_var2"
echo "{\"key1\": \"$env_var1\", \"key2\": \"$env_var2\"}"
echo '{"key1": "'"$env_var1"', "key2": "'"$env_var2"'"}'
```

I'd probably recommend the first of these as the most readable.

Comment: So I am unable to use the first printf option - 2nd is good and I tried a bit but same issue, I get the string that I can pass through sed or perl to get to your format but then interpolation doesn’t work. My real constraint is I get an arbitrary json with ${xyz} in between that I don’t know in advance. I get str and then have to ensure its interpolated but other characters preserved as is.

Comment: What I've written generates the output you've described. If you want to do something else please edit your question to show what you really want to do

Comment: The correct tool is probably `jq`

Comment: Thank you, I added a constraint that the example is just to illustrate some code. The actual json is not known in advance and can be arbitrary.

Comment: ... `jq` or `jo`